# Can we get rid of the editing characters minimum?

Tags: feature-request

From time to time, I'm trying to fix just a single typo or most common the formatting of a post. In 70 % of the cases the characters minimum keep me off, especially while deleting or adding spaces or line-breaks doesn't count.

Can we get rid of the editing characters minimum, maybe just for users with more then x reputation?

Comment: I think this is what happens when you get to 2000 and edits don't need approval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only applies for suggested edits. If you have more than 2000 reputation, your edits don't go through the peer review system, and you aren't required to meet the same character requirement as suggested edits.

With regard to getting rid of the minimum limit, it has been discussed before on Meta.SO and rejected — getting 3 people to have a look at your single-character edit isn't seen as the most productive time.